# How to find Mouse movement direction?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I need to find out the direction (Left or RIGHT) of a mouse from the moment the mouse is being pressed.

I can use only the event OnMouseMove.

Using the following method I cannot get the direction as e.GetPosition(this).X it is the same value when the mouse move and when it is clicked.

Any idea how to solve it?

```
    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        currentPositionX = e.GetPosition(this).X;

        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            double deltaDirection = currentPositionX - e.GetPosition(this).X;
            direction = deltaDirection > 0 ? 1 : -1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is almost complete. You just need to check the current position separately for both cases: when the button is pressed and when it's not:

```
protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        double deltaDirection = currentPositionX - e.GetPosition(this).X;
        direction = deltaDirection > 0 ? 1 : -1;
        currentPositionX = e.GetPosition(this).X;
    }
    else
    {
        currentPositionX = e.GetPosition(this).X;
    }
}
```

Moving to the right will result in -1 and moving to the left returns 1.