# How to get mouse movement direction in WPF (C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, mousemove, panning

I want to track mouse movement direction (left/right/up/down/diagonal) in WPF. I saw [this answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23865345/how-to-find-mouse-movement-direction) but it didn't work for me. So I wrote some code as seen below 
This is how my logic works First, I get the previous mouse position anytime the mouse moves over the window AND right button isn't held down. when the right button is held down and mouse is moving, I get current position and pass both current and previous position to GEtMouseDirection() which returns the direction. The issue is this, the method returns direction as "NONE" 7/10 of the time. But the other 3/10 of the times, it gives the correct direction, So what I'm thinking is that the mouse move event is fired so frequently that both 'currentPosition' and "previousPosition' are almost always THE SAME. I don't want this to happen because I need this to be accurate.

Also worth noting is that I have tried handling mouse move events for ImageControl and Border. But but returns the same result. So I'm pretty sure the issue is not about where I choose to handle mouse move event.

var pTx = imageControl.TransformToAncestor(imageBorder).Transform(new System.Windows.Point(0, 0));

Now coming to the reason why I want to get accurate mouse movement direction, I'm working on an image viewer and I want to restrict panning when for example the image is zoomed, mouse is moving towards the RIGHT and the LEFT of image is already aligned with LEFT of the border containing my image. ( that is when pTx.X >=0 . Does anyone have a better solution on how to get mouse movement direction or how restrict panning when image is already aligned?

('pre' for previous mouse location, 'cur' for current location).

```
    public static MouseDirection GetMouseDirection(Point pre, Point cur)
    {
        // Mouse moved up
        if ((pre.X == cur.X) && (pre.Y > cur.Y))
            return MouseDirection.Up;

        // Mouse moved down
        if ((pre.X == cur.X) && (pre.Y < cur.Y))
            return MouseDirection.Down;

        // Mouse moved left
        if ((pre.X > cur.X) && (pre.Y == cur.Y))
            return MouseDirection.Left;

        // Mouse moved right
        if ((pre.X < cur.X) && (pre.Y == cur.Y))
            return MouseDirection.Right;

        // Mouse moved diagonally up-right
        if ((pre.X < cur.X) && (pre.Y > cur.Y))
            return MouseDirection.TopRight;
        //return MouseDirection.Up;

        // Mouse moved diagonally up-left
        if ((pre.X > cur.X) && (pre.Y > cur.Y))
            return MouseDirection.TopLeft;
        //return MouseDirection.Up;

        // Mouse moved diagonally down-right
        if ((pre.X < cur.X) && (pre.Y < cur.Y))
            return MouseDirection.BottomRight;
        //return MouseDirection.Down;

        // Mouse moved diagonally down-left
        if ((pre.X > cur.X) && (pre.Y < cur.Y))
            return MouseDirection.BottomLeft;
        //return MouseDirection.Down;

        // Mouse didn't move
        return MouseDirection.None;
    }
```

Comment: How about something like `Vector.AngleBetween(cur - pre, new Vector(0, 1))`?

Comment: Haven't tried that. But how do I get direction from this equation? It returns a double.

Comment: It's an angle... Like a compass course.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my solution. Below is my code

Mouse direction enum

```
public enum MouseDirection
{
    None,
    Up,
    Down,
    Left,
    Right,
    TopLeft,
    TopRight,
    BottomLeft,
    BottomRight,
}
```

Method to calculate mouse direction

```
    public static MouseDirection GetMouseDirection(Point pre, Point cur)
    {
        // Mouse moved up
        if ((pre.X == cur.X) && (pre.Y > cur.Y))
            return MouseDirection.Up;

        // Mouse moved down
        if ((pre.X == cur.X) && (pre.Y < cur.Y))
            return MouseDirection.Down;

        // Mouse moved left
        if ((pre.X > cur.X) && (pre.Y == cur.Y))
            return MouseDirection.Left;

        // Mouse moved right
        if ((pre.X < cur.X) && (pre.Y == cur.Y))
            return MouseDirection.Right;

        // Mouse moved diagonally up-right
        if ((pre.X < cur.X) && (pre.Y > cur.Y))
            return MouseDirection.TopRight;
        //return MouseDirection.Up;

        // Mouse moved diagonally up-left
        if ((pre.X > cur.X) && (pre.Y > cur.Y))
            return MouseDirection.TopLeft;
        //return MouseDirection.Up;

        // Mouse moved diagonally down-right
        if ((pre.X < cur.X) && (pre.Y < cur.Y))
            return MouseDirection.BottomRight;
        //return MouseDirection.Down;

        // Mouse moved diagonally down-left
        if ((pre.X > cur.X) && (pre.Y < cur.Y))
            return MouseDirection.BottomLeft;
        //return MouseDirection.Down;

        // Mouse didn't move
        return MouseDirection.None;
    }
```

mouse move event handler and properties

```
    static System.Windows.Point pre = new System.Windows.Point();
    static System.Windows.Point cur = new System.Windows.Point();

    private void Panel2_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            cur = e.GetPosition(panel2);

            bool mouseMoved = (pre != cur);

            if (mouseMoved)
                direction = MouseMovement.GetMouseDirection(pre, cur);

            pre = cur;
        }
        else
            pre = e.GetPosition(panel2);
    }
```

Comment: Amazing! Worked like charm :)